# Problems using setMarginEnd and setMarginStart on Android

Tags: android, layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to set some margins by code. Nevertheless I'm having troubles setting the Start and End margins. For a strange reason using the methods setMarginStart and setMarginEnd does not modify the view left and right margins. I'm attaching the code that I'm using:

```
    RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams  params = (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) loopMainLayout.getLayoutParams();
    float fabRadius = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fab_size) / 2;
    params.bottomMargin = (int) (params.bottomMargin + fabRadius);
    params.topMargin = (int) (params.topMargin + fabRadius);
    params.setMarginEnd(params.getMarginEnd() + (int) fabRadius);
    params.setMarginStart(params.getMarginStart() + (int) 
    loopMainLayout.setLayoutParams(
```

Am I missing any kind of function call here in order to let the layout calculate the end and start margins?

Note: If I use params.leftMargin and params.rightMargin everything woks as supposed. But I'm trying to use end and start margins as best practice.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue. I'm running tests with API 22. Setting params.rightMargin works, but params.setMarginEnd() does not do anything.   Did you by any chance manage to understand this?

Comment: Not at all... my guess is that margin Start and End are only used at creation time, so you'll have to stick to the old way of setting margins...

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party but I found a working solution for whoever will stumble upon this like me. You need to call `setLayoutParams(LayoutParams)` back on the view with the updated params as per documentation in the source code (look for `MarginLayoutParams.startMargin|endMargin`) [`MarginLayoutParams`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#L8104)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are targeting an API level less than 17, which is when start and end margins were added. In that case, you might want to have a look at [MarginLayoutParamsCompat.setMarginStart(params, margin)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MarginLayoutParamsCompat.html#setMarginStart(android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams,%20int)), and see if it solves your problems.

Comment: No that's not the case, the app target is 'L' preview so unless that's a know bug I don't think the problem is related with the API Level.

Comment: Did you try using the compatability method I linked? What API level are you testing the app on?

Comment: Yeah already try it and no success. I'm currently targeting L preview only.

Answer (score 0):

setMarginStart/End seems to have no effect with "supportRtl" set to false in Android Manifest. That may be the case.